# beamer + exsheets package

Tags: beamer, exsheets

Is it possible to use `exsheets` package with beamer class? I try to do so, but this piece of code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

gives an error

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/environment-already-defined"
! 
! Environment 'solution' already defined!
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

What should be done to make `exsheets` package  work with `beamer`?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 7):

In order for `exsheets` to be able to define its `solution` environment you need to “delete” `beamer`'s `solution` environment by letting the macro `\solution` to `\relax`:

```
\let\solution\relax
```

If you also want to be able to use `beamer`'s `solution` environment alongside `exsheets` you'd need to save the macros `\solution` and `\endsolution` first:

```
\let\beamersolution\solution
\let\endbeamersolution\endsolution
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% save beamer's `solution' environment as `beamersolution':
\let\beamersolution\solution
\let\endbeamersolution\endsolution

% "delete" the `solution' environment:
\let\solution\relax

\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{question}
    A question.
  \end{question}
  \begin{solution}[print]
    The solution.
  \end{solution}
  \begin{beamersolution}
    The original \texttt{solution} environment.
  \end{beamersolution}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]