# probsoln's solution environment in beamer documentclass

Tags: beamer, probsoln

When compiling this piece of code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%% save beamer's `solution' environment as `beamersolution':
%\let\beamersolution\solution
%\let\endbeamersolution\endsolution

%%% "delete" the `solution' environment:
%\let\solution\relax

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{probsoln}

\renewcommand{\solutionname}{Answer}

\begin{defproblem}{prob1} 
\begin{onlyproblem} 
To be or not to be?
\end{onlyproblem} 
\begin{onlysolution} 
\begin{solution}
That was the question. This is the answer.
\end{solution} 
\end{onlysolution} 
\end{defproblem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \color{red}
    \useproblem{prob1}

    \showanswers
    \useproblem{prob1}
\end{document}
```

in article document class everything works as it should, that is:
[image]

All text is red and the name of the solution environment is "Answer".

Unfortunately beamer document class has got its own solution environment and presented code doesn't affect solution environment provided by probsoln. I get

[image]

Uncommenting commented lines
helps [with the problem in exsheets package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187905/beamer-exsheets-package), but it doesn't work with probsoln. What should I do to get solution environment colored in red and change its name?

Comment: `probsoln` only defines the `solution` environment if it isn't already defined, so you need to undefine `\solution` and `\endsolution` before you load `probsoln` if you want to use `probsoln`'s version.

Comment: ok. I've got it. Adding \let\solution\undefined and \let\endsolution\undefined
solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

`probsoln` only defines the `solution` environment if it isn't already defined. If you actually want to use `probsoln`'s version of `solution` you need to undefine the `solution` environment before loading `probsoln`. Undefining an environment is similar to undefining a command, but you need to take into account the command used to end the environment as well as the one that starts the environment. (Typically, `\begin{foo}` does `\foo` and `\end{foo}` does `\endfoo` if that command exists.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%% save beamer's `solution' environment as `beamersolution':
\let\beamersolution\solution
\let\endbeamersolution\endsolution

%%% "delete" the `solution' environment:
\let\solution\relax
\let\endsolution\relax

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{probsoln}

\renewcommand{\solutionname}{Answer}

\begin{defproblem}{prob1}
\begin{onlyproblem}
To be or not to be?
\end{onlyproblem}
\begin{onlysolution}
\begin{solution}
That was the question. This is the answer.
\end{solution}
\end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \color{red}
    \useproblem{prob1}

    \showanswers
    \useproblem{prob1}
\end{document}
```