# How to make svmono class work with exsheets package?

Tags: exsheets, sv-classes

I've been writing notes in tufte-book class, but it keeps giving me unidentifiable errors. So I'm changing to svmono class. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work with exsheets package. To produce both a handout and notes for myself, the exsheets package is the best solution I found. So, I need this package.

Some of the errors are as follows:

```
Undefined control sequence. 
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exsheets/exsheets.sty, line 213
<argument> \@cntfmts@err@counter@defined 
                                     {question}
l.213 ...Pattern* [ exsheets ] { question } { qu }

The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
\def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling
(e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about 
whatever was undefined.

/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exsheets/exsheets.sty, line 2770
! LaTeX error: "xparse/environment-already-defined"
! Environment 'question' already defined!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H <return>.

l.2770 \DeclareQuestionProperty
                           {counter}
| You have used \NewDocumentEnvironment with an environment that already has a
| definition.
| The existing definition of 'question' will be overwritten.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\NewQuSolPair{example}[name=Example]{examplesol}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter 
\chapter{Integer}
\section{The Division Algorithm}
\begin{theorem}
  Given integers $a$ and $b$, with $b>0$ there exist unique integers $q$ and 
  $r$ satisfying \[a=qb+r\ (0 \leq r <b).\] The integers $q$ and $r$ are called,
  respectively, the quotient and remainder in the division of $a$ by $b$.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't have the `svmono` class but the problem sounds very similar to this one: [beamer + exsheets package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187905/5049) I imagine the solution is similar, too.

Comment: With your solution, other errors are sorted out (question/solution/example), and the last one is as follows: "Undefined control sequence. /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exsheets/exsheets.sty, line 213 <argument> \@cntfmts@err@counter@defined"

Comment: That's due to two reasons: 1) a bug in the `cntformats` package. 2) because the `question` counter is already defined when you load `exsheets`. Add `\undef\thequestion` to your preamble and you should be fine. (`\undef` is provided by the `etoolbox` package which is loaded by `cntformats`)

Comment: Thank you. By adding `\usepackage{cntformats}` and `\undef\thequestion`, everything is resolved.

Comment: `\usepackage{cntformats}` is redundant: it is already loaded by `exsheets`

Comment: You're right. I don't know why it didn't compile without it before.

Answer (score 1):

The `svmono` class already defines environments `{question}` and `{solution}` In order to make `exsheets` work the essential macros from these environments must be undefined:

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\undef\thequestion
\undef\question
\undef\solution

\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\NewQuSolPair{example}[name=Example]{examplesol}` will also lead to an error because `svmono` also defines an environment `example`.